# Size changing graph using Boost graph

Tags: c++, boost, graph

Hi I am pretty new to the Boost libraries. I want to build a graph from a square two dimensional map that will be used for a star algorithm (the map is an array with 1s and 0s for both wall and normal terrain).

The graph should be undirected and change with the size of the map. Each node has 8 edges (except for sides of the map).

I've gone through a few examples but I don't understand the procedure for building graphs of this size since most examples look like this (look bellow) in the boost graph library documentation.

Any help or ideas will be really appreciated

```
    #include <iostream>                  // for std::cout
  #include <utility>                   // for std::pair
  #include <algorithm>                 // for std::for_each
  #include <boost/graph/graph_traits.hpp>
  #include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
  #include <boost/graph/dijkstra_shortest_paths.hpp>

  using namespace boost;

  int main(int,char*[])
  {
    // create a typedef for the Graph type
    typedef adjacency_list<vecS, vecS, bidirectionalS> Graph;

    // Make convenient labels for the vertices
    enum { A, B, C, D, E, N };
    const int num_vertices = N;
    const char* name = "ABCDE";

    // writing out the edges in the graph
    typedef std::pair<int, int> Edge;
    Edge edge_array[] =
    { Edge(A,B), Edge(A,D), Edge(C,A), Edge(D,C),
      Edge(C,E), Edge(B,D), Edge(D,E) };
    const int num_edges = sizeof(edge_array)/sizeof(edge_array[0]);

    // declare a graph object
    Graph g(num_vertices);

    // add the edges to the graph object
    for (int i = 0; i < num_edges; ++i){
      add_edge(edge_array[i].first, edge_array[i].second, g);
    }
    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_graph seems related

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On second reading of the question it seems like your question is simply how to add nodes and edges.

Here's a start that queries for the number of rows/columns and creates the square "grid". I use a `nodes` matrix on the side to have easy lookup from (x,y) in the grid to the vertex descriptor in the graph.

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8188ce5f91844567)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graph_utility.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost;

struct Point {
    int x, y; 
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Point p) {
        return os << "[" << p.x << "," << p.y << "]";
    }
};

int main() {
    using std::vector;
    using Graph             = adjacency_list<setS, vecS, undirectedS, Point>;
    using vertex_descriptor = Graph::vertex_descriptor;

    Graph lattuce;

    int num_rows;
    if (!(std::cin >> num_rows && num_rows > 0))
        return 255;

    vector<vector<vertex_descriptor> > nodes(num_rows, vector<vertex_descriptor>(num_rows));

    for (auto i = 0; i < num_rows; ++i)
        for (auto j = 0; j < num_rows; ++j)
            nodes[i][j] = add_vertex(Point{i,j}, lattuce);

    auto is_valid = [num_rows](Point p) { return (p.x >= 0 && p.x < num_rows) && 
                                                 (p.y >= 0 && p.y < num_rows); };

    for (auto vd : make_iterator_range(vertices(lattuce))) {
        auto p = lattuce[vd];

        for (Point neighbour : {
                Point { p.x - 1, p.y - 1 }, Point { p.x - 1, p.y + 0 }, Point { p.x - 1, p.y + 1 },
                Point { p.x + 0, p.y - 1 }, Point { p.x + 0, p.y + 1 },
                Point { p.x + 1, p.y - 1 }, Point { p.x + 1, p.y + 0 }, Point { p.x + 1, p.y + 1 },
            })
        {
            if (is_valid(neighbour))
                add_edge(nodes[neighbour.x][neighbour.y], vd, lattuce);
        };
    }

    print_graph(lattuce, get(vertex_bundle, lattuce));
}
```

Prints, e.g. for input `3`:

```
[0,0] <--> [0,1] [1,0] [1,1] 
[0,1] <--> [0,0] [0,2] [1,0] [1,1] [1,2] 
[0,2] <--> [0,1] [1,1] [1,2] 
[1,0] <--> [0,0] [0,1] [1,1] [2,0] [2,1] 
[1,1] <--> [0,0] [0,1] [0,2] [1,0] [1,2] [2,0] [2,1] [2,2] 
[1,2] <--> [0,1] [0,2] [1,1] [2,1] [2,2] 
[2,0] <--> [1,0] [1,1] [2,1] 
[2,1] <--> [1,0] [1,1] [1,2] [2,0] [2,2] 
[2,2] <--> [1,1] [1,2] [2,1]
```

Comment: The Adjacency Matrix would not be able to implement the boost a star algorithm right? Also, I thought it was used for denser graphs?

Comment: Graphs don't "implement" algorithms. Perhaps you can clarify what you mean by that. And, yes, the `adjacency_matrix` type favours denser graphs. If you knew about these, why didn't you mention it in the question?

Comment: Sorry if I don't explain myself clearly this is my second language and I am new with boost. From reading http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/graph/doc/AdjacencyMatrix.html I understood that if I use this class I would not be able to use Boost Graph Library algorithms. Also, my main question is how to add edges and vertices using for loops that change with the size of the map. And thank you very much for taking the time to answer my questions

Comment: (fixed a "bug" that added duplicate edges)